# A little php/html help

Tags: magento-1.9, backorder

So I got some php code, but I want to separate the 'echo' from the 'echo this' so I can put them into 2 DIVs so that I can give them individual css (I have posted the exact code from my site). This code is to give a frontend message so that people can see that items are for backorder BEFORE the checkout phase.

```
<div class="extra-info">

<?php $inventory =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$inv_qty = (int)$inventory->getQty();
if ($inventory->getBackorders() >= 0 && $inv_qty == 0) {
    echo "TO ORDER - LEAD TIME APROX. 3 WEEKS";
} else {
    echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability');
} 
?>
            </div>
```

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $inventory =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$inv_qty = (int)$inventory->getQty();
if ($inventory->getBackorders() >= 0 && $inv_qty == 0) {
?>
<div class="extra-info-a">TO ORDER - LEAD TIME APROX. 3 WEEKS</div>
<?php
} else {
?>
<div class="extra-info-b"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability');?></div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks for that, was struggling for a day to get it to work, but was so simple. Thanks again